# append to nested NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nested

I have a list of NumPy arrays:

```py
self.xy_lat_lon_list = [array([3986139.12431615, 3889959.08475953]),
                        array([3987252.31922408, 3889959.08475953]),
                        array([3988365.51413201, 3889959.08475953]),
                        array([3989478.70903994, 3889959.08475953]),
                        array([3990591.90394788, 3889959.08475953]),
                        array([3991705.09885581, 3889959.08475953]),
                        array([3992818.29376374, 3889959.08475953]),....]
```

I need to append an integer to every array (the same one) 
for example:

```py
uav_elev = 1900
```

output:

```py
self.xy_lat_lon_list = [array([3986139.12431615, 3889959.08475953,1900]),
                        array([3987252.31922408, 3889959.08475953,1900]),
                        array([3988365.51413201, 3889959.08475953,1900]),
                        array([3989478.70903994, 3889959.08475953,1900]),
                        array([3990591.90394788, 3889959.08475953,1900]),
                        array([3991705.09885581, 3889959.08475953,1900]),
                        array([3992818.29376374, 3889959.08475953,1900]),....]
```

I tried to use list comprehension, but got lost somewhere.

And in a regular for loop:

```py
for l in self.xy_lat_lon_list:
    l. # I thought that I will get append or insert here but It's not.
```

Comment: `xy_lat_lon_list = [np.append(a, uav_elev) for a in xy_lat_lon_list]`

Comment: Appending a value to an array requires making a new one.  And you can't mix floats and integers in an array.  Have you tried `np.vstack` to turn the list into a 2d array?

Answer (score 1):

making your list:

```
In [107]: alist = [np.array([3986139.12431615, 3889959.08475953]), 
     ...:                         np.array([3987252.31922408, 3889959.08475953])
     ...: , 
     ...:                         np.array([3988365.51413201, 3889959.08475953])
     ...: , 
     ...:                         np.array([3989478.70903994, 3889959.08475953])
     ...: ] 
     ...:                                                                       
In [108]: alist                                                                 
Out[108]: 
[array([3986139.12431615, 3889959.08475953]),
 array([3987252.31922408, 3889959.08475953]),
 array([3988365.51413201, 3889959.08475953]),
 array([3989478.70903994, 3889959.08475953])]
```

Adding the value individually to each array:

```
In [109]: [np.concatenate((arr, [1900]),axis=0) for arr in alist]               
Out[109]: 
[array([3.98613912e+06, 3.88995908e+06, 1.90000000e+03]),
 array([3.98725232e+06, 3.88995908e+06, 1.90000000e+03]),
 array([3.98836551e+06, 3.88995908e+06, 1.90000000e+03]),
 array([3.98947871e+06, 3.88995908e+06, 1.90000000e+03])]
```

`np.append` would work here as well.  It is just an alternate way of calling `concatenate`.

Or you could join the arrays into one 2d array (as long as they are the same size):

```
In [110]: arr = np.vstack(alist)                                                
In [111]: arr                                                                   
Out[111]: 
array([[3986139.12431615, 3889959.08475953],
       [3987252.31922408, 3889959.08475953],
       [3988365.51413201, 3889959.08475953],
       [3989478.70903994, 3889959.08475953]])
```

and concatenate a vertical column of values:

```
In [112]: np.concatenate((arr, np.ones((4,1))*1900), axis=1)                    
Out[112]: 
array([[3.98613912e+06, 3.88995908e+06, 1.90000000e+03],
       [3.98725232e+06, 3.88995908e+06, 1.90000000e+03],
       [3.98836551e+06, 3.88995908e+06, 1.90000000e+03],
       [3.98947871e+06, 3.88995908e+06, 1.90000000e+03]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The [insert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) function does exactly what you want:

```
np.insert(self.xy_lat_lon_list, 2, uav_elev, axis=1)
```

It returns a 2D array though, so if you need to convert it back to a list of 1D arrays just apply the `list()` function on it.